# Condicional en botones en javaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola compañeros tengo el siguiente codigo el cual el proposito es depende de cual boton le des te mostra una imagen y el nombre del personaje, la imagen me lo muestra y su nombre pero en el primero funciona correctamente pero en el segundo no me funciona porque me sigue saliendo el nombre del primero y ademas el que le corresponde.

la verdad estuve pensando en otra funcion en cual manejara este problema pero  se me hace algo enredoso lo cual probocaria codigo pasta?

Que opinan ustedes?

Mi Codigo Actual:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<title>Mario Bros</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 




 function red(){

  document.getElementById('myImage').src='indice.jpeg';
     document.getElementById("mario").innerHTML = "Mario Bros";
 }

function verde(){
       document.getElementById('myImage').src='luchi.jpeg';
      document.getElementById("luchi").innerHTML = "Luchi";


}


</script>
<h1>Mario Bros</h1>



<img id="myImage" src="http://www.esucesos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/mario-bros.-1.jpg" style="width:100px">


<p id="mario"></p>
<p id="luchi"></p>
<button onclick="red();">Mario</button>

<button onclick="verde();">Luchi</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que cuando presionas el primer botón llenas el primer <p>, cuando presionas el segundo botón llenas el segundo <p>, así que están los dos llenos, puedes ya sea vaciar el <p> que no corresponde o usar un solo <p> donde sustituir el  contenido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución: en lugar de 2 `<p>`, utiliza **solo 1**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<title>Mario Bros</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function red(){
  document.getElementById('myImage').src='indice.jpeg';
  document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Mario Bros";
 }

function verde(){
       document.getElementById('myImage').src='luchi.jpeg';
      document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Luchi";
}
</script>
<h1>Mario Bros</h1>

<img id="myImage" src="http://www.esucesos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/mario-bros.-1.jpg" style="width:100px">


<p id="texto"></p>

<button onclick="red();">Mario</button>

<button onclick="verde();">Luchi</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias algo tan simpre pero mil gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Viendo la solucion de Trauma le agrege algo que me faltaba y algo muy importante un boton para restaurar todo al principio y gracias a la aportacion de Trauma lo hice.

Mi codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<title>Mario Bros</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 




 function red(){

  document.getElementById('myImage').src='indice.jpeg';
    document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Mario Bros -Personaje Principal";
    document.getElementById("creador").innerHTML = "Gilberto Quintero";
}

function verde(){
       document.getElementById('myImage').src='luchi.jpeg';
       document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Luchi -Hermano de Mario Bros";
       document.getElementById("creador").innerHTML = "Miguel romero";


}
function restaurarTodo(){
 document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://www.esucesos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/mario-bros.-1.jpg';

       document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Personajes del video juego Mario bros";

}




</script>
<h1 id="texto">Personajes del video juego <b>Mario bros</b></h1>



<img id="myImage" src="http://www.esucesos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/mario-bros.-1.jpg" style="width:100px">


<p id="texto"></p>
<button onclick="red();">Mario</button>

<button onclick="verde();">Luchi</button>
<p>Creador:</p>
<p id="creador"></p>
<br><br><br><br>
<button onclick="restaurarTodo();">restaurar Todo</button>

</body>
</html>
```